# How to programmatically detach debugger in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I just want to detach my debugger when exiting my application in Visual Studio. Upon closing, the cleanup process takes a few seconds and I don't want to wait. I'm working in VB.net:

```vb
Private Sub frmBladeAlignment_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object,
                                          ByVal e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    Select Case e.CloseReason
        Case CloseReason.UserClosing
            Select Case MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you wish to exit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
                Case DialogResult.Yes
                    e.Cancel = False
                Case DialogResult.No
                    e.Cancel = True
            End Select
        Case else
            e.Cancel = False
    End Select

    If Not e.CancelThen
        Me.Enabled = False
        Me.Text = "APPLICATION IS CLOSING"
        Application.DoEvents()
        If Debugger.IsAttached Then
            ' detach debugger here
        End If
    End If
End Sub

' this is an MDI application and many operations 
' are done in child forms when the main form 
' is closing
```

I have looked in the `System.Diagnostics.Debugger` class, but found nothing useful.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.Debugger.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have to use a win32 API call, have a look at the following links

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2006/03/09/detach-restrictions.aspx
[Programmatically detach debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480518/programmatically-detach-debugger)

Comment: This looks like a good answer, but the amount of time it would take me to import the API function and debug it would be more than waiting for my application to finish in the end. Thanks, accepted.

Comment: No longer a valid answer. Link is dead and you didn't put the actual answer to the question here.