# Excel 2016 crash on close with debugger attached

Tags: visual-studio-debugging, excel-2016

I have add-ins for Excel VSTO. When I debug it and close Visual Studio after debugging, Excel crashes and restarts (only Excel 2016; Excel 2007, 2010 and 2013 work fine). These crashes don't happen without debugger. Also, crashes don't happen if I detach debugger before closing Excel. It's absolutely not important what kind of add-in I debug, It can be empty add-in. Even more, If I attach debugger to excel without add-ins at all, it crashes on closing. How can I avoid it? Because it takes time to crash and also I can overlook some actual crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm currently having the **same issue with Word 2016** and according to [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cfda89a1-f1f9-4a09-bdf5-068880fc8e60/excel-2016-crashes-after-a-debug-session?forum=exceldev) there is currently no Fix for this problem. *(the MSDN discussion was caused by this [post](https://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?PAGEN_1=1&FID=5&TID=13509#nav_start))*

My workaround is to **detach from the Word Process programmatically** on the Vsto-`CloseEvent` Eventhandler. How to programmatically detach the debugger from visual studio is explained very well in this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31227508/2167804).